# C++ STL List calculate average

Tags: c++, list, stl, average

I have to correct some C++/STL code. Unfortunately I have very little C++ experience and know nothing about STL. Nevertheless I finished most of it, but the function below is still giving me problems:

C++ source:

```
double MyClass::CalculateAvg(const std::list<double> &list)
{
    double avg = 0;
    std::list<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); it++) avg += *it;
    avg /= list->size();
}
```

C++ header:

```
static double CalculateAvg(const std::list<int> &list);
```

It's most likely meant to calculate the average value from a list, but it complies with a lot of errors. I tried to search for a solutions on the web, but I couldn't find anything. I would be glad if someone could help me out.

Update:
Thank you for your quick replies. The accepted answer solved all my problems.

Comment: You should at least return the result: "return avg"

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't post the errors here? We're not psychics, you know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, the first error is there:

```
std::list<int>::iterator it;
```

You define an iterator on a list of integers, and use it to iterate on a list of doubles. Also, an iterator can only be used on a non-constant list. You need a constant operator. You should write:

```
std::list<double>::const_iterator it;
```

At last, you forgot to return the value.

**edit:** I didn't see, but you pass the list as reference, but use it as a pointer. So replace all the `list->` by `list.`

Answer (score 34):

Few things:

1. You don't return anything. (add `return avg;`)
2. The `->` operator is for pointers to objects. You have a reference to a list, so you use `list.begin()` and not `list->begin()` (same for other member functions)
3. The iterator should be a `const_iterator`, not `iterator`.

In any case, you should just do the following:

`return std::accumulate(list.begin(), list.end(), 0.0) / list.size();`

Optionally checking for `list.size() == 0` if that is possible in your use cases.

Comment: +1 for std::accumulate, bear in mind that list.size() will iterate over the list so you don't want to call it twice

Comment: `size()` is a constant time operation on some compilers, and is required to be so in C++0x.

Comment: im not sure why i put will instead of may, but yes, for todays standard size is only requiredto be O(n)

Comment: Yes, that's a small inefficiency that could be overcome, but it doesn't change the complexity of the whole operation, which remains at O(n) due to accumulate anyway.

Comment: yes it would be a constant factor of 2 if you called it twice and it really was O(n) so it would still be O(n) overall, its still worth thinking about though as people often assume size is always O(1)

Comment: It almost doubles the execution time, though. I wonder where it says list.size() should be O(1). The reason it isn't is because list.splice() is supposed to be O(1). You can't have both: I'd imagine at best list could store the size, and recalculate it only after a call to splice has invalidated it (amortized constant complexity?).

Comment: I wouldn't say that it would double running time. First, the addition of doubles is slower, and second, when doing size, the whole list will likely be in cache, making the size traversal incredibly fast (whereas the first will be slow due to the layout of a list in memory).

Comment: @Peter Alexander use empty() rather than size in case you are checking for empty :) .

Comment: Caution : list.size() returns an unsigned int value, if you have negative value in your list, you shoul cast list.size() to (int) to get the average.

Comment: Since C++11, `size()` has constant complexity even for a  list, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @PierreBdR answer,
you should also check that list->size() is greater than 0,

Right before here

```
  avg /= list.size();
```

add

```
 if (list.size()>0) 
    //avg code here.
```

Or document that the list received as an argument should not be empty.

```
   assert(list.size()>0)
```

Comment: Prefer `!list.empty()` over `list.size() > 0` - one has constant, the other linear complexity-

Comment: Yes, i keep forgetting that...damn you Java

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing editing to assure that your iterators refer to lists of the same type, you'd be much better off writing the code as a generic algorithm with the iterator type as a template parameter.

I'd also note that for `std::list`, both your original code *and* most of the posted answers have a rather serious efficiency problem: given a typical implementation of list, they iterate through the list once to add up the values, and then do it again to count the number of elements. In theory, `list.size()` *could* run in constant time without iterating through the elements, but in fact that's rarely the case (you can have constant complexity for `list::size()` or `list::splice`, but not for both at once).

I'd write the code something like:

```
template <class fwdit> 
typename fwdit::value_type arithmetic_mean(fwdit begin, fwdit end) { 

    typedef typename fwdit::value_type res_type;

    res_type sum = res_type();
    size_t count = 0;

    for (fwdit pos = begin; pos!= end; ++pos) { 
        sum += *pos;
        ++count;
    }
    return sum/count;
}
```

This is generic, so it'll continue to work (unaltered) when you realize that `std::list` was a poor choice, and you'd really be better off with `std::vector`. Likewise, if you want the arithmetic mean of some int's instead of double's, it can handle that as well (again, without changing the code). Third, even if (as suggested above) your library's implementation of `st::list::size()` happens to be linear, this still only traverses the list once, so it's likely to be around twice as fast as (a working version of) the original code.

Of course, caching can (will) affect that -- when you average a small list, the first traversal will pull the whole list into the cache, so the second traversal will usually be a lot faster (so eliminating that second traversal won't save as much time).

Comment: this will not work as expected. For example for vector<int> return type is int, but average is of type double, result will be truncated

Comment: Yes, you can use it for `vector<int>`, but any more I'd probably use `std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0) / v.size();`

Comment: @piotruś: In the end, it pretty much comes down to a question of what you expect. Why would you expect the average of `int`s to be a `double`?

Comment: because you named it "arithmetic_mean", however this will not preserve properties of arithmetic mean. In particular: If numbers x_1, ..., x_n have mean x, then (x_1-x) + ... + (x_n-x) = 0. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean

Comment: @piotruś: Sorry, but you're not making much sense. Integer math is integer math. Floating point math is floating point math. You shouldn't expect integers to turn into floating point just because it's a mean. If you want something like PHP that converts types in senseless ways at the drop of a hat...use PHP.

Comment: even you seem to expect this providing your second solution: std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0) / v.size(); and yes you should expect arithmetic mean to return correct result. Floating or integer math has nothing to do about this

Comment: @piotruś: I wrote that to produce a double because you asked for it in your first comment. Integer vs. floating point *is* the (whole) question here. The problem here is in your expectation, nothing else.

Comment: IMO function is wrong written. This returns something, but definitely not average mean, and also not any statistic known to me. You should warn what it does and change it's name or change it's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `std::list<double>` in but you create a `std::list<int>` iterator? And your prototype takes a `std::list<int>` also.

Comment: Shouldn't these be comments instead?

Answer (score 1):

As Maurits Rijk said, you haven't returned avg. In addition, what errors is it compiling with?

Comment: If you want to comment, use comments!

Answer (score 1):

Since `list` is a reference rather than a pointer, you don't need the `->` dereference operator but rather just the `.` operator, i.e. `it = list.begin()` and so on.

Additionally, as everyone else has pointed out, the template type parameters for list and its iterator all need to match: either `<int>` or `<double>`. It looks like the function was originally written to accept a list of `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise for yourself. Once you get it working you should transform it into a [for_each](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html). It's easier to understand in the long term.

-- edit --

[Accumulate](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html) is better since it is meant for binary numeric operations.

Comment: for_each is almost never a good choice for an algorithm, here accumulate would be better

Answer (score 0):

With more complex object one can also use accumulate with a binary operator as follow :

```
auto accObjectValueA = [](double acc, const MyObject& object){ return acc + object.getValueA(); };
double sumValueA = std::accumulate(listOfObjects.begin(), listOfObjects.end(), 0, accObjectValueA );
double averageValueA = sumValueA  / listOfObjects.size();
```